# PHP paths from within included files

Tags: php, relative-path

**Scenario**

I have 2 files: `file.php` and `admin/file.php`

`file.php` has `require_once 'admin/functions.php';`

`admin/file.php` has `require_once 'functions.php';`

So they're both including the same file. The trouble is that within `functions.php`, things like `file_get_contents` and `include` and `require` see those defined paths as relative to `file.php` and `admin/file.php`, not the `functions.php`.

Because of this, I can't use the same `functions.php` from different directories without creating duplicate files which I don't think is the best thing to be doing incase I edit one, I'll have to remember to edit the other as well.

What's the best practice for this type of situation?

**EDIT:** See comment on accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the best practice for this type of situation?

Easy. Just set a base path manually in a config file & don’t worry about it—relative paths—ever again.

That said, if you are trying to simplify the way that files are loaded, you should explicitly set a `$BASE_PATH` like this:

```
$BASE_PATH = '/full/path/to/your/codebase/here/';
```

If you don’t know what your file system base path is, just place this line of code in your PHP code; like `index.php`:

```
echo "Your path is: " . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "<br />";
```

Then load that page. Somewhere near the top will be this text:

> Your path is: /full/path/to/your/codebase/here/

Then with that set you can change your code to be something like this:

And then set your `include_once` like this:

```
include_once $BASE_PATH  . 'includes/myfile.php';
```

Some might say you should use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or even `dirname(__FILE__)` directly with the implication being that you can simplify code portability that way. But the way file paths are set for installs can vary so it just never works well & the chances of you getting snagged on an odd server quirk is high.

It’s always best to just to manually set a `$BASE_PATH` in a config file when you move code than deal with the headaches caused by PHP constants like `$_SERVER` not being consistent between installs, setups & configurations.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. And once I recognized it as the same practice used in almost ALL CSM's I've seen, it clicked for me.

I've created 2 config files (one for the admin dir and one for the base dir):
Admin config.php: `define(ADMIN_PATH,realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/');`
Base config.php: `define(ADMIN_PATH,realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/admin/');`

I hope this clarifies the solution for someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use constants such as `__DIR__` or `__FILE__` then it may make things easier.

functions.php:

`require __DIR__ . '/../foo.php'; // will be one directory lower than admin'
'require __DIR__ . '/bar.php'; // will be in admin directory`

Answer (score -1):

I particularly always create a file containing directories of paths and urls patterns on my system. And from the moment I start to develop my system, any include or require me to do, I put that full path. In your case it would be the best thing to do at the moment.

One detail, `require_once` does not call the file again. It checks if that file has already been called and then ignores the call.

Answer (score -1):

There's no easy way without having to modify your two function.php files to use absolute paths instead of leaving them as relative paths.  Even if you could make the current code work through clever tricks, it would make your life more difficult in the future.

I would declare a variable at the top of the file, stick a path into it, and then reuse the variable throughout the function

```
$my_root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

or

```
$my_root="/usr/docs/etc/etc";  //if you don't trust the server.
```

and then just search for paths within the file and change them

for function the file outside the admin folder
change from

```
require "folder1/folder2";
```

to

```
require $my_root . "/folder1/folder2";
```

and for function the file in the admin folder

from

```
require "folder1/folder2";
```

to

```
require $my_root . "/admin/folder1/folder2";
```

Follow the same logic for any dynamic data.

This may be a lot of tedious work, but you end up with less convolution and you may end up thanking yourself later.  Even if you could make the current code work through